# Facebook bot get rid of default message

Tags: facebook, bots

I am following tutorial from https://github.com/jw84/messenger-bot-tutorial 
I am getting this message "The Default answer block is your bot’s default response to any input from a user. Create messages in this block that will guide your users. You can add buttons that lead users to other blocks. Remember, you also can use “AI Setup” to choose what blocks to show based on users' input."  everytime I write anything random in messenger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This response is generated automatically by chatfuel. Check to see if you have linked chatfuel to your bot. If you intentionally used chatfuel you can change its default response from the dashboard. If you were like me, I setup chatfuel initially but decided it wasn't robust enough for what I wanted to do, and then I used Howdy botkit, but the chatfuel ai was still linked so I got the chatfuel default message + howdy botkit responses. I had to delete the chatfuel link so that I could only get responses from Howdy.